# Remove pin mapview?

Tags: android, android-mapview

I am working on GoogleMap with MapView.Part of my project i am touching on the map and i am adding pin.My question is i want to remove pin which can added before. How can i do that i want to give Geopoint to the function.

Can anybody give me suggestion?

This is my code:`

```
public void AddPoint(Drawable drawable, MapView mapView, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        p = mapView.getProjection().fromPixels(
                (int) motionEvent.getX(),
                (int) motionEvent.getY()-50);


        final MapController mc = mapView.getController();
        mc.setZoom(16);
        CustomItemizedOverlay<CustomOverlayItem> itemizedOverlay = new CustomItemizedOverlay<CustomOverlayItem>(drawable, mapView);

        itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(new CustomOverlayItem(p,"","",""));
        mapView.getOverlays().add(itemizedOverlay);



        mc.animateTo(p);

        mapView.invalidate();
    }`
```

Answer (score 3):

```
mapView.getOverlays().clear();
```

Comment: I can use it but if i add 5 pin and if i call this code i think it will be remove all pin.İ want to just remove which i can touch.I am not sure it is work?

Comment: first change your question as per your comment ,,,,And You have to put code in onTouchEvent  to clear particular item(pin)....

Answer (score 0):

Call marker.remove().  To get the reference to the marker, you need to save the markers to a List when you create them, and then you can iterate over the List to find the ones you want.